# "Press enter" while in a bash pipe

Tags: bash, io-redirection

OK, the title may not be very clear. I was trying to do something very simple: loop through a file line by line, and add a simple `read` to wait each time for the user to press enter. But it reads from the pipe instead of stdin. I've tried to use some redirections but did not find the right incantation:

```
sort -R words.list |  while read p; do speak "$p"; read; done
```

It's pretty obvious why the above doesn't work. But can I do something like `read <&0` or `read -u /dev/stdin` on the 2nd read ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read <&1`

```sh
sort -R word.list | while read p; do speak "$p"; read <&1; done
```

➤ [Bash File Descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Moving-File-Descriptors)

> 3.6.8 **Duplicating File Descriptors**
>
> The redirection operator
>
> ```
> [n]<&word
> ```
>
> is used to duplicate input file descriptors. If word expands to one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by n is made to be a copy of that file descriptor. If the digits in word do not specify a file descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs. If word evaluates to ‘-’, file descriptor n is closed. If n is not specified, the standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.

➤ [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections)
➤ [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate input fd and use the duplicate.

```
# duplicate 10 fd as 0
exec 10<&0
sort -R word.list | while read p; do speak "$p"; read -u 10; done
```

You can redirect it for this command only:

```
{ sort -R word.list | while read p; do speak "$p"; read -u 10; done; } 10<&0
```